# is it possible to retrieve back the argument's datatype in called function when using same function for different input data types in c?

Tags: c

i have to use same function for different data types to avoid extra functions and lengthy code. 
i am taking (void*) argument in function and want to retrieve back the same datatype that i have sent from main. i.e if int comes from main, i should be able to guess the int datatype from void* of "func". here's sample function...

```
void func(void* input)
{
    if(input is int)
        printf("%d", input);
    else if (input is char)
        printf("%c", input);
    else if (input is struct)
        //do somthing;
    }
```

and the main is:

```
int main()
{
    int q=1;
    char w='c';
    func(&q);
    func(&w);
    func(&struct);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "No". The common approach is to pass a 'tagged struct/union' (or rely on other context data, such as fscanf).

Comment: @user2864740: You can fudge it in C11 with a wrapper macro though, e.g. `#define func(p) (printf(_Generic(*(p), int: "%d", char: "%c"), (p)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function argument is declared as a `void *` then any type information is not available to the function. C does not provide a way to inspect a `void *` variable to determine it real type.

This means that when a function such as you describe with a `void *` argument is being used with multiple types then the argument must include some kind of annotation or indication as to the type.

One standard way is to use a `struct` which contains a type indicator followed by a `union` of all the various types supported.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short  usType;
    union {
        int iValue;
        float fValue;
    } U;
} MyVoidType;
```

Another way is to use a `void *` argument for the thing to be processed by the function with a second argument indicating the type.

```
func(void *pItem, unsigned short usType)
{
    switch (usType) {
        case 1:
            {
                ItemType1 *pItem1 = pItem;
                // do things with pItem1
            }
            break;
        //  other cases for other types
    }
}
```

This is similar to the problems that can be experienced when using the `varargs` variable arguments functionality. With `varargs` the compile knows there are additional arguments however their type is not checked because the type information for the other arguments are not part of the function definition/declaration. The `printf()` family of output functions provides a work around to this with the format specifiers which the functions use to determine the type of an argument and from that how to format the value to print the argument.

There are problems with this approach because there is a need to maintain the annotation or indication with the actual data item and to make sure that any new types are supported with the appropriate changes in `switch` statements. It also ends up causing a problem with the compile now being unable to do argument checking for you.

So what I have also done is something like the following. In a file I have a single function that handles all the various types I want to handle. This function is then wrapped in multiple versions with the appropriate typed arguments which do nothing more than call the single function with the proper annotation.

```
static short funcmain(void *pItem, unsigned short usType)
{
    switch (usType) {
        case 1:
            {
                ItemType1 *pItem1 = pItem;
                // do things with pItem1
            }
            break;
        // other case statements
    }
}

short funcType1 (ItemType1 *pItem)
{
    return funcmain (pItem, 1);
}

short funcType2 (ItemType2 *pItem)
{
    return funcmain (pItem, 2);
}
```